# Change Menu Styling on fly or pass a param inside jQuery .each iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, coding-style

I have a bunch of menu links and want to change their style on click - say you click "about" and it becomes bold and red. I select the items and bind click event to them:

```
$("#nav_menu > *").bind("click",function(){doTrigger(this.id);});
```

this way I pass the ID of the clicked item to `doTrigger`.

Ok. Now in `doTrigger` I am trying to iterate through the items and change their styles: all to *style1* and clicked to *style2* for example. The problem is that:

```
$("#nav_menu > *").each(function(){;});
```

will not let me pass the id of the clicked item.

I think there should be a less complicated way of getting what I need. Besides, I think I am lost, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#nav_menu > *").bind("click",function(){ $("#nav_menu > *").attr('class', 'class1'); $(this).attr('class', 'class2'); });
```

This resets all children to `class1` when an item is clicked, and then only that item is `class2`.

Answer (score 0):

the function passed to `$.each()` in `doTrigger()` runs in the context of and thus has access to variables in `doTrigger()` - you don't need to pass anything

```
function doTrigger(id) {
...
   $("#nav_menu > *").each(function(){ /* you can access var id in here */ ;});
```